# How many possible values are there for $k$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> If $6x+1.5y+0\cdot z = k$ and $x+y+z = 25$ where $x,y,z$ are nonnegative integers, how many possible values are there for $k$?

I would solve this by substituting in for $x$ to get $6(25-y-z)+1.5y = 150-4.5y-6z = k$. Then it gets tricky because I still have to find all possible values of this with the constraint that $x+y+z = 25$, so I get stuck here

Comment: `Length@DeleteDuplicates[
  6 #[[1]] + 3/2 #[[2]] & /@ 
   Flatten[Permutations@# & /@ (IntegerPartitions[28, {3}] - 1), 1]]` gives $98$

Comment: @Martin How do I solve it mathematically?

Comment: well, all values $0,3/2,3,9/2,6\dots,141$ are possible, plus three extra values of $144, 291/2, 150$ at tail end.

Comment: Why isn't $142.5$ possible?

Comment: when $x=23$, $y$ cannot $=3$

Answer (score 1):

Multiply both sides of the equation $150−4.5y−6z=k$ by $2$ to get
 and 285
$300 - 9y - 12z = 2k$.

Since the GCD of $300$, $9$, and $12$ is $3$, we have at most $101$ possible values for $k$, as $2k$ must be in the set

{$0, 3, 6, 9, ..., 300$}.

We can eliminate $297$, $294$, and $285$ from the set, since no values of $y$ and $z$ give us those numbers.

This leaves $98$ possible values for $2k$ and hence for $k$.  Are all $98$ achievable under the constraint that $y+z$ is at most $25$?